# SQL SELECT .... NOT IN query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, notin

I have created a linked server for accessing an online DB so that I can select new records from the online DB and insert them to the local DB based on the customer ID.
Here is my query for selecting new records:

```
SELECT * FROM [194.0.252.151].onlineDB.dbo.customers 
WHERE [194.0.252.151].onlineDB.dbo.customers.CustomerID 
NOT IN 
(SELECT CustomerID FROM LocalDB.dbo.customers)
```

Let me say, operations like selection from onlineDB works just fine, but the above code doesn't return the required (new) records from onlineDB.
The error says:

```
The multi-part identifier "194.0.252.151.onlineDB.dbo.customers.CustomerID" could not be bound.
```

I can't figure out the mistake I have made.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try this ?

SELECT * FROM [194.0.252.151].onlineDB.dbo.customers  OnlineDatabase
WHERE OnlineDatabase.CustomerID 
NOT IN 
(SELECT LocalDatabase.CustomerID FROM LocalDB.dbo.customers LocalDatabase)

Comment: Try using alias like this `SELECT * FROM [194.0.252.151].onlineDB.dbo.customers As cust 
WHERE cust.CustomerID 
NOT IN 
(SELECT CustomerID FROM LocalDB.dbo.customers)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify the server name in front of column

Please go for

```
SELECT * FROM [194.0.252.151].onlineDB.dbo.customers 
WHERE CustomerID 
NOT IN 
(SELECT CustomerID FROM LocalDB.dbo.customers)
```

I think it should work